# how do i compare 2 visible div numbers and display a div based on a number threshhold?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to code my following theory in jquery but i'm having trouble since im more of a front end designer/developer, i don't deal very much with comparing/parsing.

I have a div(#product) that contains 2 spans. 1 span that contains a number('.price-ship-1') and another hidden span that also contains a number ('.price-ship-2').

'.price-ship-1' always exists, and '.price-ship-2' exists some of the time; How do i check to see if both exist at the same time within '#product'?

If only '.price-ship-1' exists, base my number parsing from that number and display a hidden div. But if both exist, base my number parsing on '.price-ship-2' and add a class.

Currently i'm only checking 1 number and adding a class to another div but now need to check an additional number and add a class but i'm not sure how to write it. I realize i don't need the check below since '.price-ship-1' always exists, its only in there because I was trying to write it myself, but to no avail.

my current script is as follows:

```
if ($('.promo-ship-1').length){

$('.promo-ship-1').each(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    var number=$this.html();
    number=number.substring(1);
    number=parseFloat(number);
    if(number > 99){$this.parents('.ship-banner').addClass('test123');}
});
}
```

Thank you for your time!

UPDATE:
i inherited the code and don't know it 100% yet. reading deeper into it, my issue is actually more complex than i initially thought... i may have to close the question for my purpose, but im sure somebody else may find it useful.

Comment: Tip: `$(selector).is(':visible');`

Comment: @MelanciaUK what if it exists and is hidden?

Comment: `$('#product').find('[class^=promo-ship]:visible').length == 2` means both are there and visible.

Comment: Use `$this.text();` to get exact text, html will return html formatted text. -- This is just an Off-topic help

Comment: where/when do you wanna check or test this scenario? I mean is it in an event? or a function or something else?

Comment: this is a function based off of the condition a certain class exists on a product. i inherited the code and don't know it 100% yet. reading deeper into it, my issue is actually more complex than i initially thought... i may have to close the question for my purpose, but im sure somebody else may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've shared I've written a piece of code that would simulate your scenario. I believe you can use most of it in your own code:

```js
$(function () {
    // Just to work out the elements existence and visibility.
    function calculate() {
        var prod = $('#product');
        var span1 = prod.find('.price-ship-1');
        var span2 = span1.siblings('.price-ship-2');
        var p = $('p');
        
        if (span2.length <= 0) {
            // Second element isn't there.
            p.text('Second element is not there');
        }
        else if (span2.is(':visible')) {
            // Second element is there and is visible.
            p.text('Second element is there and is visible');
        }
        else {
            // Second element is there and is invisible.
            p.text('Second element is there and is invisible');
        }
    }
    
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        var op = $(this).data('id');
        var el = $('#product .price-ship-2');

        switch (op) {
            case 'show':
                el.show();
                break;
            case 'hide':
                el.hide();
                break;
            case 'remove':
                el.remove();
                break;
            case 'add':
                $('<span>', {
                    class: 'price-ship-2'
                }).text('50.00').appendTo($('#product')).show();
        }
        
        calculate();
    });
    
    calculate();
});
```

```css
.price-ship-2 {
    display: none;
}
#product {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product">
    <span class="price-ship-1">100.00</span>
    <span class="price-ship-2">50.00</span>
</div>
<button data-id="show">Show price-ship-2</button>
<button data-id="hide">Hide price-ship-2</button>
<button data-id="remove">Remove price-ship-2</button>
<button data-id="add">Add price-ship-2</button>
<p></p>
```

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckmefL7v/)

Answer (score 0):

1. check if `$('#product').find('span').length` is 1 or 2
2. depending upon the value you can parse the number and manipulate both the divs. There is no need for each statement.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check the existence of both price-ship-1 and price-ship-2 and both are beneath a div with id #product then it is more simple.

```
 //try to only query the dom once, it is an expensive op
 var productDiv = $('#product')
 if (productDiv.length) {
     productDiv.each(function () {
         var $this = jQuery(this);
         var priceShip2 = $('.price-ship-2', $this)
         if (priceShip2.length) {
             //PRICE 2 EXISTS
         } else {
             //ONLY PRICE 1 EXISTS
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Why go through an `.each()` for `productDiv` when its `length` should be just 1 (if it exists)? The selector is an `id` and `ids` should be unique.

Comment: Also you're not checking for the second element `visibility`. It can be there, but can also be invisible.